# Passing parameter to cfprogressbar

Tags: coldfusion, progress-bar

Using ColdFusion 2018, and trying to add a progress bar on an API call.Created a cfc function to fetch this API details. For this called a "getStatus()" function through bind params. And able to load the cfprogress bar successfully. The problem is that I need to pass an en extra parameter to this getstatus function . Is it possible?

Please see the sample code I tried to load cfprogressbar

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    </head>
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
    
    function startProgress() {
    ColdFusion.ProgressBar.start("mydataProgressbar");
    };
    
    
    function onfinish() {
    alert("Done");
    };
    </script>
    
    <body>
    <cfif IsDefined("Session.STATUS")>
    <cfscript>
    StructDelete(Session,"STATUS");
    </cfscript>
    </cfif>
    
    <cfset sjsondata = '{"name":"Jibin","id":"1234"}'>
    <!--- For code simplicity, formatting is minimal. --->
    <cfform name="kitform">
    <p>To make our service better and to benefit from our special offers,
    take a moment to give us your email address and send us a comment.</p>
    <p>Name:
    &nbsp;<cfinput type="text" name="name"> </p>
    <p>E-mail:
    &nbsp;<cfinput type="text" name="email"> </p>
    <p>Comment:
    &nbsp;<cftextarea name="cmnt"/></p>
    <p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <cfoutput>
    <cfinput type="hidden" name="jsondata" value="#sjsondata#">
    </cfoutput>
    <cfinput type="button" name="bttn1" value="Send Comment"
    onClick=startProgress()></p>
    <!--- The progressbar control --->
    <cfinput type="button" name="bttn2" value="Send Comment 2"
    onClick=startProgress2()></p>
    <div style="padding-left:3px" >
    
    
    <cfprogressbar name="mydataProgressbar"
    bind="cfc:progressbar.getstatus({jsondata})"
    interval="1700"
    width="200"
    oncomplete="onfinish"/>
    
    
    </cfform>
    </body>
    </html> 
    
    File progressbar.cfc
    
    <cfcomponent name="progressbar">
    <cffunction name="getstatus" access="remote">
    <cfargument name="jsonData" type="string" required="false">
    
    <cfset str = StructNew()>
    <cfset str.message = "Saving Data">
    <cfif NOT IsDefined("session.STATUS")>
    <cfset session.STATUS = 0.1>
    <cfscript>
    Sleep(200);
    </cfscript>
    <cfelseif session.STATUS LT 0.9>
    <cfset session.STATUS=session.STATUS + .1>
    <cfscript>
    Sleep(200);
    </cfscript>
    <cfelse>
    <cfset str.message = "Done...">
    <cfset session.STATUS="1.0">
    </cfif>
    <cfset str.status = session.STATUS>
    <cfreturn str>
    </cffunction>
    
    </cfcomponent>
```

Question 1: Is there a way to pass parameter to cfprogressbar getstatus() function?

Question 2: Is there any other alternative method to implement this process in progressbar.

Comment: Sorry to say this, but times have changed and this kind of progress bar implementation as well as the use of cfinput and cfform desperately needs to be refactored. There are much better ways to accomplish this. I suggest avoiding the use of cfform or cfinput or any other kind of ColdFusion front end stuff, which have been problematic on many levels from their inception. ColdFusion is awesome at doing what it should be doing... back end stuff. Leave front end stuff for other tech like react or vue.js or even jquery.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can only give @Redtopia 1 upvote. UI is definitely not something ColdFusion should bother itself with. Fortunately, a lot of work went into solving this problem, check out https://static.raymondcamden.com/cfuitherightway/index.html. He also specifically has a way to better implement `cfprogressbar`. https://static.raymondcamden.com/cfuitherightway/cfprogressbar/index.html

Comment: I agree with Redtopia 100%. I would only add, that I would work with Bootstrap Vue to get it done. Bootstrap has progress bar stuff. VueJS can do processing in the background.

Comment: Thank you all for the feedback